# Why is my Natural Earth map not shown correctly in QGIS? (strange circle; only Caucasian Sea shown)

Tags: qgis

Using the world map data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) I have some problems with the correct displaying in QGIS.

Shapefiles added:

- 1:10 Admin Countries
- 1:10 Oceans

As you can see in my screenshot, there are some mistakes:

- A strange **circle** appears (small red frame)
- **Russia** ist not shown
- The ocean layer is only shown for the **Caucasian Sea** (blue polygon)

On some scales or projections the ocean is illustrated but up to now, I have not detected when and why this happens. The added shapefiles are not edited or rendered dependend on scale.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us the QGIS version and your OS?

Comment: It is 1.8.0 Lisboa and my OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to view these Shapefiles in any ESRI product like free ArcGIS explorer?

Comment: The circle is a country feature identified as the "Baykonur Cosmodrome"; it really is part of that shapefile.  I cannot reproduce the rendering problems in QGIS 1.8.0, but it is apparent from the screenshot that an unusual projection has been selected: it appears to be a projection specifically for only a small part of the world.  Which one is it and how was it applied to the dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the missing ocean, the answer is simple: you have selected EPSG:3857 or another transverse mercator projection as project CRS. Theses CRS are not defined at north and south pole, which is part of the ocean shapefile. Switch to EPSG:4326, and you see all seas.

Maybe the same appies for Russia.

Answer (score 3):

The "Strange Circle" is the Baikonur Cosmodrome.  It's a polygon in the Natural Earth data set.  It's a space launch platform owned by Kazakhstan and is leased to Russia until 2050.